# ICMP with jdk1.8.0_73 and jdk1.8.0_112

Tags: java, icmp

I have a program (not mine) thats uses isReachable. The problem is that the program comes with jdk1.8.0_73 and in that java version the program is unable to send ICMP request.

The developer of the program say that they not having this kind of problem with other installations.

From the developer of the program i got a .jar for testing. If I use the testing .jar in the same subnet it works with the older jdk version. But if I am trying against a IP on a diffrent Subnet the result is False.

If I use it with jdk1.8.0_112 the test result is always TRUE, even between two subnets.

How can the result be diffrent using jdk1.8.0_73 or jdk1.8.0_112? 
How can I get it to work with the older jdk1.8.0_73 between two subnets?

When I use wireshark I can see it falling back to ECHO on Port 7 when it fails ICMP. But when ICMP fails I cant see any trace why in Wireshark.

Our enviroment is Windows server 2016.

Comment: Just because https://i.imgflip.com/69rl3.jpg